# Assign IP's to certian mac addresses in dd-wrt

Tags: dd-wrt, ip-address, mac-address

I have a Linksys `WRT54G/GL/GS` that I am running `DD-WRT v24-sp2 (10/10/09) vpn - build 13064` on it and for the life of me I can not find a way to assign ip's based on Mac address. Basically I have a few laptops and Windows really has no decent way to have separate profiles for each network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assigning IP addresses based on MAC addresses is generally done by the DHCP server; this is often referred to as "static leases".

Here's the [DD-WRT tutorial on enabling Static DHCP](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Static_DHCP#Configuration).  In the web administration GUI, you'll find this option on the *Services* tab, in the DHCP Server options.

If you're using the ssh commandline interface, use the following commands:

- builds earlier than 13832:

  ```
  # X is the total number of static leases
  nvram set static_leasenum=X

  # note the space between the two example addresses
  nvram set static_leases="00:11:22:33:44:55=name1=IP-Address1 00:11:22:33:44:56=name2=IP-Address2"
  ```
- build 13832 and later:

  ```
  # X is the total number of static leases
  nvram set static_leasenum=X

  # note the space between the two example addresses
  # the last field is new; lease time; leave empty for "indefinite"
  nvram set static_leases="00:11:22:33:44:55=name1=IP-Address1= 00:11:22:33:44:56=name2=IP-Address2=1440"
  ```

[image]

Comment: the procedure may differ if you've replaced the default DHCP server with DNSmasq; see http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php?title=DNSMasq_as_DHCP_server

Comment: Perfect thanks. Was hoping for a web based way but this works perfectly as well.

Comment: MrStatic: There *is* a web based way. To quote quack quixote - `In the web administration GUI, you'll find this option on the Services  tab, in the DHCP Server options.`

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost: The web based way is broken for a lot of people, including me. I'm on DD-WRT v24-sp2 (06/14/11) and the web interface for adding static leases just plain doesn't work. It gives no errors. It just does nothing. Searching shows that a lot of people have this issue.

Comment: BTW, don't define extra leases or none of them will be saved. X must be the exact number defined in following statement.